# Why is Geany giving me a Build/Compile error?

Tags: c#, compilation, raspberry-pi, geany

When I try to build/compile my files in Geany to run them, I am met with this error: `make: *** No targets specified and no file found.` I tried making a custom target with a similar error given. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Is there a Makefile inside the folder of your file?

Comment: Yes, I've tried build & makefile.

Comment: No. Do you create a Makefile for your project. Geany cannot guess this for you. You have to create a minimalistic Makefile